# Does convergence everywhere imply convergence in mean square?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real-valued square integrable random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ satisfying $\forall \omega \in \Omega, X_n(\omega) \to 0.$

Do we have $\text{E}(X_n^2) \to 0$? If so, how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. For a (celebrated) example, take $\Omega = (0, 1]$, $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{B}((0, 1])$ and $P = \lambda$, the Lebesgue measure on $(0, 1]$. Define 
$$X_n(\omega) = \sqrt{n}I_{(0, 1/n)}(\omega), \; n = 1, 2, \ldots.$$
Then $X_n(\omega) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$. While
$$E(X_n^2) \equiv 1$$
which doesn't converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

*Remark:* It's better to say $X_n$ converge everywhere instead of "converge for every random event" since "event" is a set rather than a point.

In general, converge almost surely and converge in moments are not implied by each other. To derive convergence in moments from convergence almost surely, you need additional assumptions such as dominated convergence theorem's condition or uniform integrability.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the links between usual convergence notions (a.s., $L^p$, probability, distribution), but I was hoping that the upgrade from almost everywhere to everywhere might alleviate the need for monotone or dominated convergence theorem.